# Why does React.js not work with Twitter's Typeahead library

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm using react for my application and i've noticed the Twitter Typeahead library  doesn't work when I try to use inside React components. 
I know there are plenty of other react autocomplete libraries out there but I was wondering why it doesn't work with Twitter's typeahead when react is known to work well with jQuery and multiple other libraries

Updated:

As an example I used the fb avatar example code and tried to use typeahead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>


    <div>
      <div id="bloodhound">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of US"/>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>

     <script type="text/jsx">


var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

    // constructs the suggestion engine
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: states
});



$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: states
});



var Avatar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProfilePic username={this.props.username} />
        <ProfileLink username={this.props.username} />
        <div id="bloodhound">
        <div><input className="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of US"/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ProfilePic = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <img src={'https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.props.username + '/picture'} />
    );
  }
});

var ProfileLink = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a href={'https://www.facebook.com/' + this.props.username}>
        {this.props.username}
      </a>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Avatar username="sports" />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
    </script>
</html>
```

The box that does is outside of the component works but not the same box when rendered within a react component. My original problem is very similar to this and hence I have used this example

Comment: I use typeahead in a react component, too, and it works. Can you show some code?

Comment: You need to bind the input events (typeahead:selected and typeahed:autocompleted) to update your component state (setting the value of the input field for example)

Comment: Thanks Thilo. Could you correct the above code so I know what you are talking about

Comment: Also, the typeahead initialization for the component has to be done in `componentDidMount`. Couldn't find a good example online, sorry. +1 for the question.

Comment: @sarathjoseph How to handle the input chnage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this updated answer

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>


    <div>
      <div id="bloodhound">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of US"/>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>

     <script type="text/jsx">


var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

    // constructs the suggestion engine
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: states
});



$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: states
});



var Avatar = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myTextInput).focus();
    $ (React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myTextInput)).typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      source: states
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log('resd');
    return (
      <div>
        <ProfilePic username={this.props.username} />
        <ProfileLink username={this.props.username} />
        <div id="bloodhound">
        <div>
          <input className="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of US" ref="myTextInput" name="sahan" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleChange} /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ProfilePic = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <img src={'https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.props.username + '/picture'} />
    );
  }
});

var ProfileLink = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <a href={'https://www.facebook.com/' + this.props.username}>
        {this.props.username}
      </a>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Avatar username="sports" />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated for the latest React API: https://gist.github.com/rjurney/70725bac99df3684faa150198c9a0a23

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery within a React JS app is usually not necessary.  In general there is more often than not a react alternative for a JQuery dependent library.

Googling for "Bloodhound react js" let me to https://github.com/erikschlegel/React-Twitter-Typeahead , which is suited for react js and does not require JQuery.

Comment: Bloodhound react js does in face require jquery. see https://github.com/erikschlegel/React-Twitter-Typeahead#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

An updated answer (for the latest React) might look like: https://gist.github.com/rjurney/70725bac99df3684faa150198c9a0a23

I can't get the code to paste right.